# AngularJS basic app not working

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angularJS, recently started learning. While I was going through a video tutorial, I was trying the app side by side. At some point I got stuck and not able to figure out where I went wrong. Kindly Help!

```
<div>
    <!-- Placeholder for views -->
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<script src= "lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
            })
        .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers= [
        {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix'}, 
        {name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York'}, 
        {name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'San Francisco'}
        ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
            { 
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city 
            });
    }
});
</script>
```

This was index.html file. View 1 is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng- repeat="cust in customers | filter : filter.name | orderBy : city"></li>
</ul>

<br />
Customer Name: <br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
<br />
Customer City: <br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
<br />
<button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
<br />
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
```

View 2 is ass follows:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 2</h2>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="city"/>
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng- repeat="cust in customers | filter : city | orderBy : name"></li>
</ul>
```

Where am I going wrong? I am getting blank output.

Comment: What is the issue that you face? I mean, when you say you are stuck, what happened?

Comment: no output. I am getting a blank page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the ngRoute module. It was put into its own module a few releases ago.

Make this change and see if it works:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

You have included the script file for it but have not indicated that demoApp has a dependency on it.